# How to force List<Float> to all be between 0.0 and 1.0?

Tags: android, kotlin, floating-point

I'm writing this function in Kotlin for Android:

`fun giveMeSomeFloats(floats: List<Float>)`

I want `floats` to contain floats between 0.0 and 1.0.

I noticed you can use this annotation `@FloatRange` to achieve something similar:

`fun giveMeAFloat(@FloatRange(from = 0.0, to = 1.0) float: Float)`

This works, as callers cannot pass floats outside of that range. But this only works for `float` and not `List<Float>`.

`fun giveMeSomeFloats(@FloatRange(from = 0.0, to = 1.0) floats: List<Float>)`

Here, someone can actually pass in `listOf(1.2f)`.

Is there a way you can force a `List<Float>>` to all be within a certain range?

Comment: What do you want it to do?  Do you want it to throw an exception when someone tries?  Just ignore the number and skip it?  Fail to compile?  It really depends.  The first two can be done by just make a child class of list that overrides any function which adds new data to check.  You could probably even make it work based on the annotation with some reflection, although it will cost speed.  If you want it to not compile, you're going to have much more work and learn annotation processing.  It also would still be possible to do via a variable, unless every float in the app is ranged properly.

Comment: Maybe kotlin arrow meta is what you need: https://arrow-kt.io/docs/meta/analysis/conditions/

Answer (score 0):

Inside the function, you can use `filter` to only consume the values within the specified range in the `List`.

```
fun giveMeSomeFloats(floats: List<Float>) {
  val filteredFloats = floats.filter { it in 0.0f..1.0f }
  // filteredFloats is in the range 0.0f to 1.0f
}
```

If you instead want to raise an exception if any value is not in range then you can use `any`

```
fun giveMeSomeFloats(floats: List<Float>) {
  if(floats.any { it !in 0.0f..1.0f }) {
    throw Exception("Not in range")
  }
  // floats is confirmed to be in said limits
}
```